# How to format Ints from datePicker to date-string

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime-format

I am able to get the date values from date picker:

```
override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
    Log.i("onDateSet", year.toString())
    Log.i("onDateSet", month.toString())
    Log.i("onDateSet", dayOfMonth.toString())
}
```

How can I format this ints into date-string, something like this for example: `2020-05-05`

And I saw that the month always returning one month ago, if today is 5th month, it's returning 4th month.
Is it a bug or I just how it works and I need to add 1 to every month I'm getting from date picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc says that `month int: the selected month (0-11 for compatibility with Calendar#MONTH)`, so yeah, this is the desired behavior and to format it to human readable you have to add 1 I suppose.

And for formatting a string you should probably manually concat the data you have

```
val date = "$year-${month+1}-$day"
```

(the quickest way to me, but you may choose some prettier one)

Alternatively you could do:

```
val date = LocalDate(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth).toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Thank you for youe answer, the "problem" with your way is that the returning ints are "5" instead of "05". I mean, I can calculate all the possiblites, but i'm sure there is a "cleanier" way for this formatting

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Then I'd probably suggest creating a 
`val localDate = LocalDate(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth)` and then using `localDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: Unfortunately does not work either...```LocalDate.of()``` is only from API level 26, and even then I coudn't pass year-month-day paramaters

Comment: Ah, right, sorry, I was using org.joda.time.LocalDate

Comment: I imported LocalDate using ```threetenabp``` and  yout answer works perfect, just remove the format in ```toString```.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [AndroidSDK's Date class](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html),

> A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.
>
> An hour is represented by an integer from 0 to 23. Thus, the hour from midnight to 1 a.m. is hour 0, and the hour from noon to 1 p.m. is hour 12.
>
> A minute is represented by an integer from 0 to 59 in the usual manner.
>
> A second is represented by an integer from 0 to 61; the values 60 and 61 occur only for leap seconds.

Date and Year are represented in the usual manner, while the things mentioned above are represented with their respective rule.

Hence if its May, it will return 4, if its June it will return 5, and so on.

**NOTE: Although this behavior may seem strange, it is consistent with the java.util.Calendar class (although it is not consistent with joda.time.DateTime).**